# What typically uses port 44380?

Tags: networking, firewall, port, tcp, udp

A company just asked me to open port 44380 in my firewall so that their software could work.

This made me wonder... what is the customary use for port 44380?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [IANA port assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), 44380 is in the unassigned range. Maybe some custom software uses it for communication

```
pmcdproxy      44322/udp   PCP server (pmcd) proxy

               44323-44552 Unassigned
```

Can't find any entry for the same in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) either

Answer (score 1):

they could have asked you to open 44379 or 44381 as well. there is no .. real reason behind their question. they just need an open port.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just their custom software needs that port. I don't see any software that is IANA registered for that port.